# I tried to run RabbitMQ server but it returned a Segmentation error?

Tags: rabbitmq, homebrew

I am trying to run a repo in my local machine that requires Postgres, RabbitMQ, Celery.

My system is a MAC.

When I try to start the rabbitmq server I get this error:

rabbitmq-server start
/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmq-server: line 150: 78860 Segmentation fault: 11  start_rabbitmq_server "$@"

I cannot seem to find a relevant answer around.

I just tried to run the rabbitMQserver but it didn't start.

Comment: a Celery repo requires Postgres, RabbitMQ in my local machine to find a relevant answer around,